# gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3> error while running fastapi in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

I have added fastapi to a docker container which does background tasks using `BackgroundTask` from fastapi. When i run the container the page is not loading and i have seen this error in docker desktop logs `gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>`. I am using `docker run -d --name mycontainer -p 8080:8080 onetest` to run the container.

`entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --config gunicorn.config.py app.main:app
```

`docker file`

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r ./requirements.txt
COPY ./app ./app
COPY ./inputs ./inputs
COPY ./model ./model
COPY ./tests ./tests
COPY ./gunicorn.config.py ./gunicorn.config.py
COPY ./Procfile ./Procfile
COPY entrypoint.sh .
EXPOSE 8080
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
CMD [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

`docker_config.py`

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:8080"
workers = 4
timeout = 300
# Using Uvicorn's Gunicorn worker class
worker_class = "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"
```

Comment: What is the port that you are using? On docker command you are using port 80, on Dockerfile you expose port 8000 and on docker_config.py you bind on port 8080.

Comment: as you pointed out i have changed every port to 8080 but still i am getting `gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>` error